# System.getenv() call in JVM

Tags: java, jvm, environment-variables

I am setting environment variable in my machine using `export MY_KEY=foo`. And I am trying to fetch it in JVM using `System.getenv("MY_KEY")`. This returns null. But running `echo $MY_KEY` shows `foo` on the terminal. 
I have tried restarting the IDE. Doesn't work, still.

Comment: Did you restart via File > Restart, or via closing the IDE and opening it?

Comment: @geffchang I closed the IDE and opened it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment variable is only available to sub processes of the shell that exported it. Did you start your IDE from that shell?

If you want the variable to be available all the time, you need to add it
to the /etc/profile file or create a extra file in /etc/profile.d. It depends on your operating system.